# Windows exe launcher for Java app with JRE check

Tags: windows, exe, java, launcher

I need to distribute a Java application and I want an installer to install it in all cases.

I need to create an `*.exe` launcher that will check the installed JREs and

1. if the required JRE isn't installed, show a window with a proper link.
2. if required JRE is installed, launch the properly executable jar file.

Comment: I you don't absolutely need a .exe file, webstart does all that for you...

Comment: Which installer are you using? NSIS? MSI? Your own? Not yet decided?

Comment: @D.R. NSIS. I know that it allows to check JRE during installation, but install it in any case - is a requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm pretty happy with WinRun4J: http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/

It's under active development and some improvements I suggested were quickly implemented.

The only thing that is currently lacking (from my point of view) is to specify a "relative" path to the JRE to allow bundling a JRE with the application.

To spare you the effort of reading the manual, this is what I do for my launcher:

Rename `WinRun4j.exe` to `MyApp.exe`, then:

```
rcedit /C MyApp.exe
rcedit /I MyApp.exe myapp.ico
rcedit /N MyApp.exe MyApp.ini
```

Put into a nice little batch file and there is no "manual" stuff to do.

You only need to do this **once** (and if your library path changes)

Comment: It looks like a tool that will solve a problem. But manual is so poor - I can't understand how to build an exe file. I've customized .ini file and chse an icon, what's next? Please help!

Comment: @Zharro: You don't need to "build" and exe. You just rename the existing one and replace the icon (as explained in the manual). This is pretty well documented. See my edit

Comment: Thank you! But could you please help me a little bit more. Please answer this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428347/how-to-fill-ini-file-for-creating-exe-for-java-app-with-libs-winrun4j] question.

Answer (score 2):

You could use JSmooth for example: http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/