# How to fill ini file for creating exe for Java app with libs (WinRun4J)

Tags: winrun4j

"MyApp" folder has now the following structure:

```
- MyApp     
  - lib
    - MyLib.jar
  - MyApp.jar
```

MyApp.jar has a manifest with `Class-Path: lib/MyLib.jar`

I want to add MyApp.exe file to "MyApp" folder. So I put all files required to create exe via WinRun4J to "MyApp" folder. Then I run bat file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15409917/925021). That gives me exe file with a proper icon but all I see when I run it is a splash screen. Where am i wrong? My ini file content:

```
main.class=my.main.class
classpath.1=lib/MyLib.jar
splash.image=SplashScreen.gif
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to include your main jar as well:

```
main.class=my.main.class
classpath.1=MyApp.jar
classpath.2=lib/MyLib.jar
splash.image=SplashScreen.gif
```

or to simply include all jars:

```
main.class=my.main.class
classpath.1=*.jar
classpath.2=lib/*.jar
splash.image=SplashScreen.gif
```