# How to finalize a java program, should it be in an .exe file?

Tags: java, installation

I made some programs in java but I don't know what I should do afterwards finalizing it for the end user. all I have is a bunch of .class and .java files in a directory and I have no idea how to distribute it to the user. Isn't java supposed to work like a normal program where I install it through a self-extracting file or InstallShield like how pc games install their programs? Thank you.

I've read on deployment but mostly I saw was how to package it into a .jar file. I'm not sure how that works but the user would most likely not be able to know what to do with a package file unless I include detailed instructions on how to operate it. I was hoping there would be a way that I install the entire java program with a .exe file like a normal program does and it will load up into a specified directory and create start menu/desktop shortcuts for the user to use.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can create an installer e.g. using IzPack: http://izpack.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.jar Files are runnable on each Plattform. That's the advantage of java. So you can roll out the .jar or you can run it into an Java-applet. Or you build an .exe launcher...

Like this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/15409917/2617699

Answer (score 1):

Export it into an executable jar using eclipse. The you can create an exe using Launch4j or any similar software.